# is there any ATL supported macro that checks the hresults and returns the value?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, error-handling, atl

I'm looking for something equivalent to the following macro:

```
#define FAILED_CHECK(hr) if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;
```

is there any implementation inside the ATL library that does as shown above?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whatever reason, ATL have not been providing an extremely useful macro like requested. Starting a few releases of Visual Studio back, ATL introduced similar macros:

```
/* Naming is slightly off in these macros
ATLENSURE_RETURN(condition) is an HRESULT return of E_FAIL
ATLENSURE_RETURN_VAL(condition, hr) is any return value (function can pick)
ATLENSURE_RETURN_HR(condition, hr) is HRESULT-specific, though currently the same as _VAL
*/
```

but once again, there was no immediate match. You have to define your own. Or alternatively, switch to throwing exceptions on error conditions. ATL provides useful macros for this: `ATLENSURE_THROW`, `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED` and friends.

In particular, you can throw exception on failure `HRESULT` using `ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED` and then catch exception, esp. before return from COM interface call, converting it back to HRESULT:

```
_ATLTRY {
  // ...
  ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pFoo->Bar()); // Bar returns HRESULT 
  // ...
} _ATLCATCH(Exception) { // CAtlException class
  return Exception; // Back to HRESULT through CAtlException's operator
}
```

Comment: ATLENSURE_SUCCEDED should not be used according to this post https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/679899/atlensure-succeeded-macro-is-unsafe-for-use-with-evaluatable-arguments

Comment: At least as of MSVC 14.29.30037, the connect issue described no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ATL-specific macro since most of ATL functions use standard **[HRESULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446131.aspx)** - see the list of **[most common HRESULT values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

There are [macros for error handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including [FAILED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SUCCEEDED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ulibrary/windows/desktop/ms687197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that are used the most:

```
#define FAILED(hr) (((HRESULT)(hr)) < 0)
#define SUCCEEDED(hr) (((HRESULT)(hr)) >= 0)
```

So you usually use these, or in specific situations you may expect specific HRESULT to be returned, thus you'll end up with checking  whether it's equal to your desired value explicitly. In this case you will most likely end with something like this:

```
HRESULT hr = ...
if (hr != S_OK)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [list of ATL macros sorted in alphabetical order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/sks11ex0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), instead this list is focused on [debugging and error reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/2hfwwtbs%28v=vs.90%29): it seems there is nothing like you requested.